# Sort Parts by sales descending and show Parts that do not have images and parameters in the last place

Tags: sql

I need to show Parts first sorted by sales (column name is sales_rotation_group) and show the Parts that do not have images and parameters on the end. In other words, first show Parts that have images and parameters and then show Parts that do not have

Let's assume the db structure is like this:

### Parts

id (String), sales_rotation_group (String), parameters_count (Integer)

### Galeries

id (Integer)
part_id (Integer)

### Images

id (Integer), galery_id (Integer)

Currently I have this SQL however it's not sorting the Parts correctly. It shows some parts with images and several parts with parameters and then parts without parameters and then again with parameters.

```
SELECT  parts.* FROM parts
LEFT OUTER JOIN galleries
ON galleries.part_id = parts.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN images ON images.gallery_id = galleries.id
GROUP BY parts.id
ORDER BY parts.sale_rotation_group DESC, COUNT(images.id) DESC, parts.parameters_count DESC
```

Should I use grouping somehow? I think I may run into a problem where a part might have good sales (be on the top of the result of the query) and have no images or parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `ORDER BY` clause to order on whether the counts are greater than 0, rather than the actual count value. This will ensure that parts with 0 images and 0 parameters sort at the end:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COUNT(images.id) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN parts.parameters_count > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         parts.sale_rotation_group DESC
```

Note that using a `UNION` won't help as the output ordering from a `UNION` query is undefined and you would still need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @jedi sorry, forgot to move `parts.sale_rotation_group` to the end of the order by... See my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in the `ORDER BY` to accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM parts p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     galleries g
     ON g.part_id = p.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     images i
     ON i.gallery_id = g.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(i.id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) DESC,
         p.parameters_count DESC;
```

You can include `p.sale_rotation_group` as the first key.  However, this is not part of your description of the desired ordering.